# Administrator for my local forums

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I finished my local forums for personal use but they are only registered members, I would like to set up an administrator for it but I have no idea how that can be started and done, if someone could help me please explain a little, I appreciate any of your help. Thank you very much.

UPDATE

Should I create a new table for administrator only ?
How can I set roles for him and other members ?

UPDATE

I wonder if an administrator may have different layout of all pages (buttons to control users, to view online users' IP addresses, to forcefully forbid an ip or an accessed browswer etc) compared to other normal users. If he may, how those are positioned and set up on all pages, that is too complex isn't that ? Or am I thinking too hard about this ?

Comment: Normally, admin is just another user with some extra privileges. Do you have the concept of user groups in your system?

Comment: No, I don't. Could you give me a link to learn about it in relation to my current problem?

Comment: The concept originates from unix, so probably the best way of learning  is something like [this](http://www.udel.edu/topics/os/unix/general/unixgroups.html). You could at [django auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) too for inspiration. Basically, have a table of groups, and a many-to-many link between the groups and users. Depending on the group to which a user belongs, you perform some actions or not.

Comment: I would like to know if a forum administrator may have different  index page as well as buttons on it to control posts and users online

Comment: This is something you need to define. BTW, cakephp has something called [access control lists](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1242/Access-Control-Lists). You should probably use this rather than re-inventing the wheel :)

Comment: please always note what cakephp version you are using. I am assuming 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

I should keep it in one users table, as I assume you do now, and keep a record in the user table for it's "level" which represents some priviliges retrieved through a LEFT-join from a other table.

This is just an example as your goal can be achieved in more ways.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would have the User table (which I assume you have already), with a "Role" field.  When somebody logs in, you can detect whether or not the user is an Admin.

If you don't need a huge amount of flexibility, you can hard-code the Admin privileges into your code.  When an action requires that the user is an Admin, you simply check against the value in the Role field.

Comment: Thank you I update my post for better clearity. please read and help me

Answer (score 0):

Add another column to your users table "Role" which defines if user is admin or not, on loggin check this field and set a session varialbe `$_SESSION['is_admin']`, then on relevent pages check if this field is set and include admin specific files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use my Tiny Auth:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/

It doesn't necessarily need a roles table (Configure does the trick) and has a setting to auto-allow all non-admin prefixed actions to users and allow all admin_ prefixed methods to the admin.
no overhead whatsoever.

this said you can either use those admin_actions to have an own backend for the admin or you can check on the role inside your templates like so:

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role_id') == Configure::read('Role.admin')) {
    //echo admin stuff inline
}
```

this will only output infos and links/buttons if you are the admin.

or you can mix those two, of course.